# Rails, show page url id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My post controller

```
def show
 @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

My post model

```
def to_param
 "#{id}-#{title}"
end
```

When anyone type url _http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/10 , then redirect to id-title page url

How display 404 page when type post id eg:_http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Slug**

`404` errors will be caused by Rails not being able to load the respected db objects - meaning if you limit the lookup in your controller to just the `slug` attribute, it *should* give you a `404` for the `id`:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
Class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @post = Post.find_by slug: params[:id]
    end
end
```

This will *only* look in the `slug` attribute - anything else will return a `no record found` exception

Comment: i remove gem friendly_id, added refre

Comment: i added my post model `  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{reference}"
  end`

Comment: `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` post controller.

Comment: That still won't work - use the code I provided and it should work for you

Comment: iam not using gem friendly_id

Comment: Right. Well you need to close your question then. My answer was for your original question - if you want to ignore it & change the question completely, please tell me beforehand so I don't waste my time again